# Android set the text of TextView inside a Fragment - where the Fragment may have already mounted

Tags: android, android-fragments

Within my Android app I'm looking to hotswap the text in a Fragment based on a button press in another fragment.

The Buttons fragment has 6 buttons, each of which need to invoke a configured view of output fragment, so that when "BUtton 1" is pressed in Buttons, a TextView myText is configured to say "Button 1 was pressed" and so on, for 2 - 6.

I've tried instantiating a member version of the TextView inside onViewCreated, and several other strategies but I can't seem to get this not to crash.

Is there an established pattern for this?

```
//MainActivity Java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements StringsFragment.OnStringsInteractionListener,
        StringFragment.OnStringInteractionListener,
        ProgressFragment.OnProgressInteractionListener {

@Override
public void onStringButtonClick(Integer string) {
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(progressFragment).commit();

    if(liveStringFlag != true) {
        liveStringFlag = true;
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_bottom, stringFragment).commit();
        stringsFragment.activateSummary();
    }

    stringFragment.updateStringData(string);
}
```

What does stringFragment.updateString need to look like, and what else needs to happen to make it work?

Comment: I think what you have to do is rearrange your first fragment to receive some input data in a bundle and set the buttons in the other fragement to make a call on the fragment manager to replace the first fragment sending it the necessary data. This means that the first fragment will get refreshed everytime a button from the second frasgment is clicked.

Comment: I'd thought so as well, however that breaks when the second button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What isn't immediately clear about this scenario is that it's sometimes tricky to know when onViewCreated has been called.  In effect this is a race condition and the update method or the onViewCreated may be called first.  For this reason it's important to carefully manage state.

```
Public Class stringFragment extends Fragment {
  private TextView textString;
  private Boolean viewable = false;
  private String string = ""; 

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        textString = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_string);
    if(string != null) {
        textString.setText(string);
    }

    viewable = true;

  }

  public void updateStringData(String s ) {
    string = s;

    if(viewable == true) {
        textString.setText(string);
    }
  }
}
```